# Detect bad shutdowns in OSX

Tags: macos, shutdown, logging, osx-yosemite

Is there a way to detect bad shutdowns in OS X?

The best I can come up with is parsing `/var/log/system.log` for lines like this:

```
12118 Jan 28 21:51:38 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1422492698 0
```

without a previous line like this:

```
12112 Jan 28 20:39:58 Pauls-iMac.local shutdown[346]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1422488398 77104
```

**What I have looked into**

I share my computer with other users and I suspect some are not shutting down the computer correctly (i.e. turning it off at the wall instead of shutting it down correctly). So I want to detect the bad shutdown on the next boot.

I heard that OS X Server logs "Improper shutdown detected" in `/var/logs/system.log`, I think however, OS X does not. Surely there is some flag that is *not* set by the system following a bad shutdown (e.g. so that disk repairs can be performed by the system later).

I checked out `dmesg` which didn't have much (no timestamps either) and the logs in Console.app, but found no message that definitively indicated an improper shutdown.

Comment: Search the log for `Previous shutdown cause` - which will lead you to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere